# FactoryBot generate content for join table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot, factory

I'm trying to use factory bot to generate test data for RSpec. My tables are as follows:

`User` -> can be `pro_team_player` or `noob_team_player` and there is a model `conversation` such that:

```
class Conversation < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :messages
  belongs_to :pro_team_player
  belongs_to :noob_team_player
end
```

So every conversation belongs to a `pro_team_player` and a `noob_team_player` and every `conversation` has many messages associated with it.

Now I have the factory for `user`, `pro_team_player`, `noob_team_player` and `messages` as:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :user do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Cool Player#{n}" }
    sequence(:email) { |n| "user#{n}@email.com" }
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :pro_team_player do
    player_type 'some type'
    user
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :noob_team_player do
    player_type 'some type'
    user
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :messages do
    content 'Hola! This is a message'
  end
end
```

Now I can generate the above data as:

```
user1 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
pro_team_player = build(:pro_team_player)
user1 = pro_team_player.user1

user2 = FactoryBot.create(:user)
noob_team_player = build(:pro_team_player)
user2 = noob_team_player.user2
```

I'm still learning FactoryBot and I've no idea how to create the `conversation` factory or generate the data for that. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are on the right track. Keep following the pattern you are using:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :conversation do
    pro_team_player
    noob_team_player
    # Other required conversation attributes, if any
  end
end

FactoryBot.define do
  factory :message do
    conversation
    # Other required message attributes, if any
  end
end
```